Are there any first century non-Biblical manuscripts attesting that writers in Palestine would write like the Alexandrian type-text?
I have read several books on both camps about whether the Byzantine text-type or Alexandrian text-types are in general closer to the autographs. However, the greater question is how the Apostles (or the associate) writing style would have looked like.
Are there any manuscripts from that time that can prove the that predominant writing style in Judea was what it is found in the Alexandrian or Byzantine type-text?
Hort says that the Byzantine type text "delighted in pronouns, conjunctions, and expletives, and supplied links of all kinds; smooth and attractive, but appreciably impoverished in sense and force." Basically, plain, simple, lucid, unpretentious. And the Alexandrian text type was the opposite. What do we see in non-Biblical manuscripts of the time?
I have read many books, and I can't find any analysis done of existing 1st century writings. The Dead Sea Scrolls have lots of those manuscripts but I have not found such analysis done on them. All I have read from experts is that they are "Koine Greek."

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help, below, as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Up-voted +1.
